# How to set defaults of the new ubuntu version after an update?

Tags: updates

I have just update my ubuntu from  12.10 to 13.04 and I would like to know what defaults are currently used ? Those of 12.10 or those of 13.04 ?

After such an update, does ubuntu uses the new defaults or keep old ones ? For example, python is still python 2.7 and I though that default version in 13.04 was python 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the dist-upgrade updates all core "programs", which are necessary for the new version. It also changes the repository's to the newer version and then update all programs, if not a update with the update-manager (or in the terminal) should solve this problem.

To be clear that the new repos are set:

1. Open update-manager
2. preferences
3. other software (the second tab on the left)
4. control if ubuntu raring main is checked

The default version of python in 13.04 is 2.7.4 (I made a clean install). But you can upgrade to python 3.